# Problem with login/logout operations while using drupal for facebook

Tags: users, 6, social-network

I'm using drupal 6 and the module [drupal for facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) v6.x-3.3 and I have a problem with the logout functionality.

Strangely when I try to logout of the website, it automatically redirects me to my facebook profile. If you return to the site, I am still logged out of it.

I don't know if is a issue of javascript or module.

I had a problem with the login, because if I tried to enter the site, the site would freeze in front page and on reloading by pressing f5, it shows up in logged in state.
Now, have a delay (the typical module) and you enter. Is there any way to remove the delay that has to quickly enter the website?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [FBOAUTH](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth) module. This module is simple and straight forward. It works out of the box with out any glitches.

Check readme file to configure Facebook Login button. Hope it resolves all your issues !